# how can refresh image tag for update image?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In this action,

```
<img style="width: 250px;height: 250px;" src="@Url.Action("InitialPicturesPersonal", "ApplicantImage", new { picId = imgLoadId2})" />
```

I catch my picture but view show last picture and not
 refresh, how i can refresh page for update image in page?

Comment: If you press F5 in the browser does your image display a different picture?

Comment: i have ajaxForm and dont press F5

Comment: When must the picture change?I would like to help you but I don't understand what the problem is...